# Wildcards don't work for filtering unanswered page

Tags: bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions

In your interesting tags you can give a wildcard symbol. So if you click on an interesting tag, you will see all questions matching your wildcard.

On the unanwered page this does not work. Take for example the unanswered page for the tag [zend*](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend~) this one contains 35 questions, (the same as for the tag [zend](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend)) while there are 141 questions for [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend-framework), something that definitely should match for [zend*](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend~).

Another funny detail is that while [zend](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend-framework) and [zend*](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend~) tags give the same page, [combined](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend~+zend) the page is empty!

Comment: Spotted well. Addendum: The combined one returns the 35 zend matches, if you switch the order of the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/zend+zend~